# .addclass is not working when page is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, css, load, addclass

I am trying to run an animation once my main page is loaded but I have a preloading system that loads and has a loading animation and hides the contents of the main page. This loads all of the sites contents (images and so on) and once completed, the main page is then visible. Once the main page is visible, I want to load some animations by using the .addclass.

Here is the HTML

```
    <header id="head" class="wrap" style="background-color:transparent;">

<div class="123">
    <ul class="abc">

<li><a href="/index.php#home" class="class1">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>            
       <li id="defg"><a>defg</a></ul></li></ul>
</div>

<div class="class2">


        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <span id="title-seperator">|</span>

</div>

</header>   

<div class="mainpart" id="mainpart"> A bunch of other nested elements with....</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
    header
    {
        margin:0 auto;
        height:11%;
        background-color:#eee;
        z-index:10;
    }
    header .animateHeader
    {
-webkit-animation: rotateInRight 4s;
-moz-animation: rotateInRight 4s; 
-o-animation: rotateInRight 4s; 
animation: rotateInRight 4s; 
    }

    #mainpart .animateMainpart
    {
-webkit-animation: fadeInRight 4s;
-moz-animation: fadeInRight 4s; 
-o-animation: fadeInRight 4s; 
animation: fadeInRight 4s;
    }
    #mainpart {
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #eee;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index: 10;
max-height: 520px;

overflow: hidden;
outline: none;
background-color: transparent;
}

    @-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
}

to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes fadeInRight {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
}
    }

    @-o-keyframes fadeInRight {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateX(300px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
}
    }

    @keyframes fadeInRight {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(300px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
    }

  @keyframes rotateInRight {
from {
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform: rotateY(-200deg);
}
to {
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
}
 @-webkit-keyframes rotateInRight {
from {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-200deg);
}
to {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
}
  @-moz-keyframes rotateInRight {
from {
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-200deg);
}
to {
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
}
  @-o-keyframes rotateInRight {
from {
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -o-transform: rotateY(-200deg);
}
to {
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
}
```

and finally, here is my JavaScript (using JQuery library)

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").preloader({
            //Preload the contents of the page before they're displayed.
        });

    });
    </script>
    <script>    
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#mainpart").addClass("animateMainpart");​
    $("header").addClass("animateHeader");​
}); 
   </script>
```

For testing purposes, I've placed and alert box inside the load function to see if the function is getting executed at all. The alert box appears only if the alert is by itself inside the .load however once I try to place the .addclass, neither the animations nor the alert appears so I know that the .load function works. It is just the matter of why the .addclass isn't working. Also my .ready function with the preloader class works just fine and isn't causing any problems so I'm sure it isn't that fault of that class.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to work ok for me: http://jsbin.com/ILEyexI/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I've ran your jsbin but there is no css in there that has the animation. The jsbin works the same way my code works. All the elements that I want to animate are shown on the page. The only problem is the elements are not first animated on the page where my load function is. Same with the jsbin, the image is being shown but not animated when the page is loaded because there are no transitions in your css. The css section of the code is empty so I assume there aren't any transitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").preloader({
            //Preload the contents of the page before they're displayed.
        });

    });

$(window).bind("load", function() {
 $("#mainpart").addClass("animateMainpart");​
        $("header").addClass("animateHeader");​
   // code here 
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's not going to work, the images may not be loaded by that stage

Comment: try now i have update the answer may that will help full for you.

Comment: Which is no different from what he had

Comment: Yeah I've made the changes according to your .bind function but I've got the same result. Does not work but I know that the .,load function is being called because like I said, when I place an alert inside the function the alert pops up. The only time it doesn't work is when I also place the .addclass inside the load function as well. So I think it is either my css or the way I try to attach the .addclass but I have know clue.